# Problems connecting two laptops using a cross-over cable?

Tags: lan

I connected two laptops using a cross-over cable. My IP Address is 192.168.1.1 and the other IP Address is 192.168.1.16. We both are able to ping each other and the reply is perfect. There is no loss of packets.

The problem is I shared a file and the other system is not able to open my IP Address using the run command. Even I am not able to open my Shared folder by giving in the run (`\\192.168.1.1`). A dialogue box with the message `\\192.168.1.1, The Network Path was not found` opens each time we try this.

But I am able to open his shared folder by giving in run command (`\\192.168.1.16`). I closed all the firewall services in my system. But still my system is not able to respond. Also we are not able to use remote desktop connection.

Can anyone please help me in solving this?

Additional Details: I use Windows XP and the other machine uses Windows 7. We both are in the same work group.

Comment: this aint the right site for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some steps to solve your problem:

1. Did you set the static IP by yourself or that come automatically?
2. If yes then please go and set the IP manually
3. Then share the file and put the permission of that file to Maximum (If you believe your partner)
4. Then power down the firewall or antivirus for some moments (say 10 minutes)
5. Now try to connect using the \192.xxx.xxx.xxx method using the Run window
6. If the 5th step is not working, then try disabling and reenabling the LAN card, then try the 5th step again.

Hope that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop needs to be explicitly enabled. Right click on "My computer", go to properties and look at the remote settings tab.

Comment: We already tried it. The remote settings are enabled in both the systems. Any other suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use Radio Access Point to connect both windows 7 and windowsXP. I think this is best choice of [troubleshoting jaringan](http://antiasap.blogspot.com/2013/04/troubleshooting-wlan-bag-1.html). why?
Because I already do anything to connect both [Operating System](http://antiasap.blogspot.com/2012/11/sistem-operasi-jaringan-dan-layanannya.html) but can't solve that problem.